# TensorFlow DecodePng throws Value Error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

For decoding a png image, normally we use the following segment of code.

```
image_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
image_tensor = tf.read_file(image_placeholder)
image_tensor = tf.image.decode_png(image_tensor, channels=1)
```

For deploying a model using Tensorflow serving, I followed the example of [Inception_saved_model](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.py) for my own version of model. Below is the code used in that program to read the incoming tensorproto.

```
image_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='images')

feature_configs = {'images': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.string), }
tf_example = tf.parse_example(image_placeholder, feature_configs)
image_tensor = tf_example['images']

image_tensor = tf.image.decode_png(image_tensor, channels=1)
```

When I use this code, Decode_png throws Value error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'DecodePng' (op: 'DecodePng') with input shapes: [?].
```

Can someone help me on where I am going wrong? The code I presented here is similar to the one given in the Inception example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.parse_example` operates on a batch ("rank 1"), and `decode_png` expects a single image (a scalar string, "rank 0"). I'd either use [tf.parse_single_example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_single_example) or add a `reshape` to scalar (`shape=[]`) before using `decode_png`.

Comment: Thanks, @Allen. Now I am getting AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="Could not parse example input, value: '�PNG' " while running client code. Could you suggest what would be the issue here?

Comment: Looks like the image data got corrupted somehow. I'd guess when the protocol buffer was created.

Comment: I have used the same example as [inception_client.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.py). Except that I changed the tensor proto's shape to be as of scalar. (shape=[]). And also the image which throws the above error while serving works properly when used in testing on the same machine.

Comment: Ah, then it's a `TensorProto` rather than a `tf.Example`. You can parse `TensorProto`s to numpy arrays with `tf.make_ndarray`, then pass them in using a `feed_dict`. In this case you'll get a scalar string from `make_ndarray`, which you can feed through a placeholder and then pass to `decode_png`.